# Python Arrow Not Formatting Date Properly

Tags: python, datetime, python-arrow

I am using the [Python Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package for formatting a date that I've got.

My input is:

```
datetime=2017-10-01T00:10:00Z and timezone=US/Pacific
```

My expected output is:

```
Sun 10/01 @ 6:10pm
```

I've tried a host of different date time conversions but I always end up with `Sun 10/01 @ 12:10AM` which is not time zone dependent.

If I try and say:

```
x = arrow.Arrow.strptime('2017-10-01T00:10:00Z', 
                         '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',
                         tzinfo=tz.gettz('US/Pacific'))
```

`x` is equal to:

```
<Arrow [2017-10-01T00:10:00-07:00]>
```

I then say:

```
x.strftime('%a %m/%d @ %I:%M%p')
```

and it outputs

```
Sun 10/01 @ 12:10AM
```

The `Arrow` object knows about the timezone as evidenced by the `-7:00` but does not format the date accordingly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are a couple of misunderstandings in this question.

#### Convert to a timezone

I can see no way that the timestamp,

```
2017-10-01T00:10:00Z and timezone=US/Pacific
```

Can become,

```
Sun 10/01 @ 6:10pm
```

There are several problems here.

1. The Z at the end of the timestamp is a timezone and means `Zulu` aka GMT, so the timestamp already has a timezone.
2. If we ignore problem #1, then for that timestamp 10 minutes after midnight (minus the Z) to become 6:10 pm the same day would require a timezone that was +18.  This timezone does not exist.
3. US/Pacific is -7/-8 depending on the time of the year.  If we accept the Z as the timezone and want to convert to US/Pacific, then the time should be 9/31 at 5:10pm

#### What does -7:00 mean?

So I am going to guess that what you intend is that the timestamp is in fact Zulu, and you want to display that timestamp as US/Pacific.  If this is true than you need to do:

```
from dateutil import tz
import arrow
x = arrow.Arrow.strptime(
    '2017-10-01T00:10:00Z',
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').to(tz.gettz('US/Pacific'))

print(x)
print(x.strftime('%a %m/%d @ %I:%M%p'))
```

This results in:

```
2017-09-30T17:10:00-07:00
Sat 09/30 @ 05:10PM
```

You will note, as you noted earlier, that these produce the same time.  The difference is that the first also has a -7:00.  This does not indicate, as you intimated in your question, that time needs to have 7 hours removed to be shown as in the timezone, it instead indicates that the timestamp has already had 7 hours removed from Zulu.